# Does pullup resistor affect the push button when enabled or disabled for a mps430 uC?

Tags: c, microcontroller, msp430

The code works as follows:
Button pressed:    green on, red off
Button ot pressed: green off, red on

All the code samples ive seen from people online had the pullup resistor enabled when using a button to toggle between the LEDs. Is this even necessary for a code to work?

I commented the line out in my code and the only change i noticed was that it turned one the reset button. Is that what its intended for?

```c
#include <msp430g2553.h>

#define LED0      BIT0
#define LED1      BIT6 
#define BUTTON    BIT3

int main(void)
{
    // Stop watchdog timer to prevent time out reset
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;
    P1DIR |= 0x40;
    P1OUT &= ~0x40;

    P1DIR |= 0x01;
    P1OUT &= ~0x01;

    P1DIR &= ~0x08;
    P1SEL &= ~0x08;
    //P1REN |=  0x08; 

    while (1) {
        if ((P1IN & 0x08) == 0) {
            P1OUT &= ~0x01;
            P1OUT |= 0x40;      
        } else {
            P1OUT |= 0x01;
            P1OUT &= ~0x40;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code seems to work as intended but am wondering what this pullup resistor is actually intended to do?

Comment: You forgot to mention how your button is wired. If it's a path to ground, you typically need a pull-up.

Comment: there are 2 switches. S1 and S2(Reset). Both switches are connected directly between the microntroller pin and ground. So yea to avoid floating errors yes i would need a pullup resistor. i just dont know how it affects my code directly. With the P1REN enabled, the reset button does nothing if pressed. if its commented out then reset toggles LEDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset line is already pulled-up by external resistor, there is no need to pull it up with internal resistor. Reset pin also is not a GPIO (port) pin, so you basically can't enable internal pull-up for it. As for `P1.3` button: some Launchpad board revisions have external pull-up resistor soldered for that button, some don't. So you should enable internal pullup for `P1.3`, just in case. When `P1.3` button is not pressed, the circuit is open and you don't want `P1.3` pin to be floating. Hence pull-up resistor required.

I found some old code of mine, it may be helpful for you. Especially pay attention to comments.

```c
/* Program demonstrates interacting with buttons (GPIO Inputs) */

#include <msp430.h>

#define LED_RED_BIT     BIT0
#define LED_GREEN_BIT   BIT6
#define BUTTON_BIT      BIT3

enum led_state {
    RED_LIGHT   = 0,
    NO_LIGHT_R  = 1,    /* no light after red led turned off */
    GREEN_LIGHT = 2,
    NO_LIGHT_G  = 3     /* no light after green led turned off */
};

enum led_state state;   /* current state of LED state machine */
static unsigned char is_button_down;

static void init_leds(void)
{
    P1DIR |= LED_GREEN_BIT | LED_RED_BIT;
    P1OUT &= ~LED_GREEN_BIT;
    P1OUT |= LED_RED_BIT;
    state = RED_LIGHT;
}

static void init_button(void)
{
    /* Since R34 is not installed -- turn on internal pull up for P1.3.
     * Details: according to LaunchPad User's Guide, section 1.3:
     * "Pullup resistor R34 and capacitor C24 on P1.3 removed to reduce
     * the current consumption"
     */
    P1OUT |= BUTTON_BIT; /* the pin is pulled up */
    P1REN |= BUTTON_BIT; /* enable pull-up resistor */
    is_button_down = 0;
}

/* Switches to next state of LED state machine */
static void trigger_led_sm(void)
{
    switch (state) {
    case RED_LIGHT:
        state = NO_LIGHT_R;
        P1OUT &= ~LED_RED_BIT;
        break;
    case NO_LIGHT_R:
        state = GREEN_LIGHT;
        P1OUT |= LED_GREEN_BIT;
        break;
    case GREEN_LIGHT:
        state = NO_LIGHT_G;
        P1OUT &= ~LED_GREEN_BIT;
        break;
    case NO_LIGHT_G:
        state = RED_LIGHT;
        P1OUT |= LED_RED_BIT;
        break;
    default:
        /* Reset state machine */
        init_leds();
        break;
    }
}

static void init(void)
{
    init_leds();
    init_button();
}

static void loop(void)
{
    /* Button polling */
    if (P1IN & BUTTON_BIT) { /* button is in released state */
        if (is_button_down) {
            is_button_down = 0;
            /* event: button up */
        }
    } else { /* button is in pressed state */
        if (!is_button_down) {
            is_button_down = 1;
            /* event: button down */
            trigger_led_sm();
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    init();
    for (;;)
        loop();

    return 0;
}
```

### UPDATE

On schematic below you can see that "RST" pin and "P1.3" pin both have dedicated external pull-up resister: R27 for RST and R34 for P1.3. But if you have new revision of board -- R34 is not soldered there, so you have to use internal pull-up.

You can find complete schematics for your Launchpad [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau318f/slau318f.pdf).

[image: Launchpad board schematic]

Comment: do reset and p1.3 each have their own pullup then? or are both tied to one but p1.3 can be configured and rst cant?

Comment: I added **UPDATE** to my answer, answering your question.

Comment: Also notice that I edited your code in your original question, and fixed some bug there: you should wrap you `else` section in curly brackets (like this: `else { ... }`), because you have more than 1 instructions in there. In your code `P1OUT &= ~0x40;` line belongs to `while` section, not to `else` section.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Your sketch helped me a lot, yet you forgot to add the line:

`WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; // Disable watchdog timer`

Comment: @Meir I didn't really forget it, I just disabled watchdog timer in my Makefile, using next GCC option: `-mdisable-watchdog`.